# Different domain with different phpmyadmin service and the "same port" problem (nginx reverse proxy, docker)

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a VPS with nginx-proxy container, and I create some wordpress website with phpmyadmin service. If I want to create another site with this definition I got "same port" problem.
Ok, I can change the port to 2998 and it works fine but I need to add a new open port to my VPS. I don't want to add or change the port for each site.

Now:

- example-a.com:2999 -> example-a phpmyadmin login page
- examlpe-b.com:2998 -> example-b phpymadmin login page

Is there a way to direct me to the appropriate container by domain address?

- example-a.com:**2999** -> example-**a** phpmyadmin login page
- examlpe-b.com:**2999** -> example-**b** phpymadmin login page

**My nginx proxy definition**

```
networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    external: false
    name: nginx-reverse-proxy
  default:
    name: nginx-reverse-proxy-default

version: '2'
services:

  nginx-proxy:
    build:
      context: .nginx-proxy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - .nginx-proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - .nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - .nginx-proxy/dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy

  nginx-proxy-acme:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-acme
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
     - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
     - .nginx-proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
     - .nginx-proxy-acme/acme:/etc/acme.sh
```

**And this is my wordpress site definition**

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  database_volume: {}

x-logging:
  &default-logging
  driver: json-file
  options:
    max-size: '1m'
    max-file: '3'
    
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./.docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_web
    container_name: test_web
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - database
      - php
    restart: always
    logging: *default-logging

  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: test_database
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wp
    volumes:
      - ./database_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    restart: always
    logging: *default-logging
  
  php:
    build:
      context: ./.docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_php
    container_name: test_php
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www
    restart: always
    logging: *default-logging
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: test_phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database:db
    ports:
      - '2999:80'
    restart: always
    logging: *default-logging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible, but you probably don't actually want it. It becomes clear once you think through what you want to configure, and what would happen if a user would go to either URL:

- you have configured `example-a.com` to point to your IP
- you have configured `example-b.com` to point to your IP
- you have configured your `nginx-proxy` container to listen on ports `80` and `443`
- you want to configure your WordPress containers to both listen on port `2999`
- you, or rather the `acme-companion`, have configured your `nginx` container to forward HTTP requests that ask for host `example-a.com` to go to the container for example A with port `2999`, and requests that ask for `example-b.com` to go to container B with port `2999`

Now, you can see right away that you have two things attempting to listen on the same network interface with port `2999` - that doesn't work, and it can't, because who would handle picking up incoming requests before the request is parsed to find out which host it wanted ? Container A can't accept the request and, if it's meant for B, hand the request over - A doesn't know about B.

So if you think about a user sending a request to `example-a.com:2999`, what really happens is that a request goes to `<yourip>:2999`, just like if a user goes to `example-b.com:2999`, it will end up going to `<yourip>:2999`.

How can that problem be solved ? By having a third container C that accepts user requests, looks into the request, and based on whether they wanted container A or B, hands the request over to A or B.

Here is the great thing: you already have that! Container C is really your `nginx` container, which is listening on port `80`/`443`. So if your users go to `example-a.com` without providing a port, it will go to `80` or `443` (depending on whether they used `http` or `https`). Then, `nginx` will analyze the request, and send it to the correct container. For this, it doesn't really matter what port A and B listen on, because to the outside world, it looks like they are listening on `80`/`443`.

So the real answer is that while you can't combine custom ports with virtual hosts and use the same port for multiple containers (other than `80`/`443`), you don't actually *NEED* custom ports in the first place! If you just configure your containers with the default ports, users can use both `https://example-a.com` and `https://example-b.com` and it will 'just work'™

Comment: I was very confused when I made all this at the end. Now, re-reading after two months, the thing is quite clear. Thanks for the detailed writing!